# How to go about calculating this finite summation?

Tags: summation

I have the summation

$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{10} \frac {1 + (-1)^n} {2^n}
$$

I have looked up how to work out sequences without manually finding each term and adding it up, but I have only found out how to work out problems like $n^2$, $n^3$, etc.

How would I solve this? Is there some way to simplify it to be able to solve it? Please be detailed.

Thanks

Comment: The numerator is $0$ when $n$ is odd, and $2$ when $n$ is even. So we get $2\left(1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{10}}\right)$. Now we have a finite geometric series, common ratio $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{0\le n\le10}\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2^n}=\sum_{0\le m\le5}\frac2{2^{2m}}$$ which is a [Geometric Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)

Comment: Are you saying that any sum $\sum_{n = k}^m f(x)$ can be rewritten as $\sum_{k \leq n \leq m} f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Finite sums are, well, finite. So we may simply expand
$$ \begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^{10}\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2^n}&=\frac{1+(-1)^0}{2^0}+\frac{1+(-1)^1}{2^1}+\frac{1+(-1)^2}{2^2}+\ldots +\frac{1+(-1)^{10}}{2^{10}}\\
&=\frac21+0+\frac24+0+\frac2{16}+0+\frac2{64}+0+\frac2{256}+0+\frac2{1024}\\
&=\frac{1024+256+64+16+4+1}{512}=\frac{1365}{512}\end{align}$$